# Form onsubmit() does not function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to control my form for the required input texts, and I have made a function in javascript. But when I click the button, and I havent fill the required field nothing the message do not appear, and I can go to the other page.
the function is:

```
function Validate(){

    // create array containing textbox elements
    var inputs = [document.getElementById('firstname1')];

    var error;

    for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
    // loop through each element to see if value is empty
    {
        if(inputs[i].value == '')
        {
            error = 'Please complete all fields.';
            alert(error);
            return false;
            }
    }
 }
```

and the part of form is:

```
<form name="password" onsubmit="return Validate()" method="post" id="password" action="#">
    <input type="submit" value="Proceed"  id="submit1" onclick="displayform2()" class="button" style=" margin-top: -40px;margin-left: 60%;width: 25%" disabled>
```

I have noticethat if I put off the onclick method in the button it works, but I should have this method at the button...How can I solve this?Please help me

```
 function displayform2() {
               /*For desktop*/
                if (document.getElementById('desktop1').style.display=='block') {
                    document.getElementById('desktop1').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('desktop2').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('desktop3').style.display='none';

        }
         /*For mobile*/
         if (document.getElementById('mobile1').style.display=='block') {
                    document.getElementById('mobile1').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('mobile2').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('mobile3').style.display='none';
                }}
```

It opens another form in the page...so when I click the button the first form dissapeared and the second form is displayed

Comment: The html shown doesn't include a `type="submit"` button. Also, what does `displayform2()` do?

Comment: yes I made the type submit and it still do not work..The method you mentioned I publish above

Answer (score 0):

You have this: `var inputs = [document.getElementById('firstname1')];`

Then you try to loop through that.  I'm betting `firstname1` is a field, so it's either null (if that field doesn't exist) or an array with only one element (the field).  It looks like you are trying to check *all* required fields, so that won't work.

I'm not 100% what you ultimately want to do, but it will likely be much easier if you use a framework like jQuery; otherwise, you are going to have to do some complicated case-handling for different browsers.

Comment: `inputs` _is_ an array, containing one element that is either the DOM element firstname1 (if it is found) or `null` (if it is not found).

Comment: True (I will edit), but I don't think that's what the OP's trying to do.  He has a `for` loop, and it looks like he's trying to check each field in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code do you call submit. That is why the function in the onsubmit handler is not triggered. If you want the button to submit the form, it would need to be a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a little unclear.  For example, you are trying to validate whether a value has been entered into the input "firstname1", but you don't have markup for that element in your HTML.

I suspect what you are trying to do is to validate whether the form has been filled out or not.  Something like the following (which validates input "firstname1") will do the job:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit1", function(){
    if($("#firstname1").val() == "" || $("#firstname1").val() == null){
        alert("Please complete all fields.");
    }
});
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fSNp6/)

The above requires jQuery, but can also be converted into vanilla JavaScript.

Load the jQuery library in the "head" section of your document by including the following code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly what i need. CAn you covert it to javascript because I have no knowledge  of jQuery..Sorry if I disturb you

Comment: When would `.val()` ever return `null`? (It will returned `undefined` if `#firstname1` doesn't exist, and `undefined==null` gives `true`, but then your code will tell the user to complete a field that doesn't exist.)

Comment: @user2804038 You just need to include a reference to the jQuery library to use jQuery syntax.  See the updated answer

Comment: @nnnnnn I guess it's just habit.  As far as the element not being defined, I've never ran into a incident where someone wrode JS validation for something that wasn't initialized in the HTML

Comment: @user2804038 Good to know you found it useful!  Please consider up-voting and accepting this answer so other people who stumble on this question will find it helpful